# Excel - Counting specific words filtered by months

Tags: excel, vba, date, excel-formula, count

I'm looking to generate the number of "Ashwin" and "Aron" in a particular month. The sample data and desired result is as below.

Can't seem to arrive at the right code to achieve the numbers in a table format. Any help will be greatly appretiated!

Sample Data :

[image]

Desired Result:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with putting the dates on the rows and making a pivot table? General Excel practice says that your set ranges should go left to right and your variables go up and down. Please check my answer for a better method

Answer (score 1):

In the desired Sheet you have to put your column name like this 1/1/2019, 1/2/2019, 1/3/2019, and format them as "mmm", in this way they will look like: Jan, Feb, March

Then you need this formula:

```
 =COUNTIFS($A$1:$F$1,">="&K$2,$A$1:$F$1,"<="&EOMONTH(K$2,0),$A$2:$F$2,$J3)
```

$A$1:$F$1 is in Sample data, the range that has dates

K$2 is the cell that has Jan

$A$2:$F$2 is in Sample data, the range that has names

[image]

in this way you will have the results requested, i just tested it.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just use a pivot table

This then becomes a much better way to go about showing data, as put in my comment:

> What's wrong with putting the dates on the rows and making a pivot table? General Excel practice says that your set ranges should go left to right and your variables go up and down. Please check my answer for a better method

[image]

[image]